# Jenkinsfile shared libraries IDE support

Tags: jenkins, import, ide, shared-libraries, jenkins-pipeline

Since my Jenkinsfile has almost 2000 lines of code(Scripted pipelines) it is obvious that it is better to refactor it to use shared libraries. The thing that stops me from that - is the way i have to import this libraries in the Jenkinsfile. Either using the `@Library` notation to import the global configured library or using library step to load library dynamically i loose code completion and possibility to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+click the method\class\variable.

Am i missing something? How do you solve this issue? It is very frustrating to return 20 years back to search manually for some method through all code base instead of simply clicking it in the IDE to find it's implementation.

Answer (score 0):

there are several things that you can do. 
First of all if your libraries have .groovy extension then use class inside, for example:

```
class NotificationLib() {
}
```

then, here in your Lib class add the methods you are interested. 
next step will be (all this assume that your pipeline and libraries are in same repository) to use @Library in pipeline, but also us import or new for the classes of your libraries
most probably you will need to have constructors in your Lib classes but that's fine.

Hope it helped.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestions. Unfortunately i found that i can't use Global library, since i want to keep the scripts in the branches to have possibility to make changes there. So my only option is to use dynamic 'library' step, which does not have imports at all. So basically from the IDE point of view(Intellij IDEA with groovy SDK) i'm getting a bunch of files which are not connected at all. And the more i split them to suitable steps the more hell with navigation i get.

Comment: do you keep Libraries in the same repository where actual pipelines files are ?

Comment: Yes, pipelines are in the same repository just one level upper relating to library. But in terms of perforce it doesn't matter.
We came to the following:
1. https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Permissive+Script+Security+Plugin allows run everything we need from dynamic library.
2. IntelliJ Idea works perfectly with completion and CTRL+Click when root directory  is marked as sources root.